# Visual traceroute for Linux with geolocation

Tags: linux, networking, data-visualization

I am on Debian Jessie. I am looking for a visual traceroute program which I can use to trace a path from my localhost to a remote host. I am looking for something which visually maps the location of each ping hope (either Google maps or any other map will also do like OpenStreetMap or something else altogether). I am looking for a GUI solution or, at least, something which has some graphics so it's easier to understand.

I came close to http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/ but rejected that one as it requires Oracle Java and does not work with OpenJDK. I also tried mtr, but that also was a big fail. See https://bugs.debian.org/772587

Now can anyone recommend something which works with Debian main and still I can visualize the path as well as maybe even export static `.png` images as well?

I have a kernel which is IPv6 enabled but have a provider who is IPv4 enabled. As far as geolocation maps are concerned the best would be something which is either in the same app. or if not some dependent package. I am not looking for something which is a web-service in terms of a web-page hence shared for something which could be a static image which basically tells all the places it pinged around the world or wherever.

**Note**: [A Visual Traceroute Program](http://kyleflan.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/a-visual-traceroute-program/) doesn't work for me. I tried to register but it needs a static IP Address and server while the connection I have is a dynamic one. Even beyond that I don't want to put any more foot-prints on the net then I have to.